# Is there an alternative to CoreTemp on windows

Tags: system-monitor

I love having my cpu temperatures on constant live display on windows 7, I would like to know if there is a way to get an extremely similar experience as CoreTemp on windows gives you, (Temperatures Displayed Live On the Toolbar like in the picture I provided) Thank you for any help you can offer as I am pretty new to Ubuntu 17.10

Comment: http://wpitchoune.net/psensor/

Comment: You question says you will include a picture but none is there?

Answer (score 1):

I like to use conky to monitor temperature, CPU utilization % by core, CPU clock frequency and GPU clock frequency:

[image: cpu 22 second.gif]

A good place to see user conky creations is [Ubuntu Forums](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=281865). The relevant code for the 22 second .gif above is:

```
${color}Today is:${color green}$alignr${time %A,}$alignr ${time %e %B %G}
${color}Distribution:${color green}$alignr ${pre_exec cat /etc/issue.net} $machine
${color}Kernel:$alignr${color green} $kernel
${color orange}${voffset 2}${hr 1}
${color2}${voffset 5}Intel® i-7 6700HQ 3.5 GHz: ${color1}@  ${color green}${freq} MHz
${color}${goto 13}CPU 0 ${goto 81}${color green}${cpu cpu1}% ${goto 131}${color3}${cpubar cpu1 18}
${color}${goto 13}CPU 1 ${goto 81}${color green}${cpu cpu2}% ${goto 131}${color3}${cpubar cpu2 18}
${color}${goto 13}CPU 2 ${goto 81}${color green}${cpu cpu3}% ${goto 131}${color3}${cpubar cpu3 18}
${color}${goto 13}CPU 3 ${goto 81}${color green}${cpu cpu4}% ${goto 131}${color3}${cpubar cpu4 18}
${color}${goto 13}CPU 4 ${goto 81}${color green}${cpu cpu5}% ${goto 131}${color3}${cpubar cpu5 18}
${color}${goto 13}CPU 5 ${goto 81}${color green}${cpu cpu6}% ${goto 131}${color3}${cpubar cpu6 18}
${color}${goto 13}CPU 6 ${goto 81}${color green}${cpu cpu7}% ${goto 131}${color3}${cpubar cpu7 18}
${color}${goto 13}CPU 7 ${goto 81}${color green}${cpu cpu8}% ${goto 131}${color3}${cpubar cpu8 18}
${color1}All CPU ${color green}${cpu}% ${goto 131}${color1}Temp: ${color green}${hwmon 0 temp 1}°C ${goto 250}${color1}Up: ${color green}$uptime
${color green}$running_processes ${color1}running of ${color green}$processes ${color1}loaded processes.
${color}Load Avg. 1-5-15 minutes: ${alignr}${color green}${execpi .001 (awk '{printf "%s/", $1}' /proc/loadavg; grep -c processor /proc/cpuinfo;) | bc -l | cut -c1-4} ${execpi .001 (awk '{printf "%s/", $2}' /proc/loadavg; grep -c processor /proc/cpuinfo;) | bc -l | cut -c1-4} ${execpi .001 (awk '{printf "%s/", $3}' /proc/loadavg; grep -c processor /proc/cpuinfo;) | bc -l | cut -c1-4}
${color orange}${hr 1}${if_existing /tmp/nvidia}
${color2}${voffset 5}${execpi .001 (nvidia-smi --query-gpu=gpu_name --format=csv,noheader)} ${color}@ ${color green}${execpi .001 (nvidia-smi --query-gpu=clocks.sm --format=csv,noheader)} ${alignr}${color}Temp: ${color green}${execpi .001 (nvidia-smi --query-gpu=temperature.gpu --format=csv,noheader)} C
${color}${voffset 5}Ver: ${color green}${execpi .001 (nvidia-smi --query-gpu=driver_version --format=csv,noheader)} ${color} P-State: ${color green}${execpi .001 (nvidia-smi --query-gpu=pstate --format=csv,noheader)} ${alignr}${color}BIOS: ${color green}${execpi .001 (nvidia-smi --query-gpu=vbios_version --format=csv,noheader)}
${color}${voffset 5}GPU:${color green}${execpi .001 (nvidia-smi --query-gpu=utilization.gpu --format=csv,noheader)} ${color}Ram:${color green}${execpi .001 (nvidia-smi --query-gpu=utilization.memory --format=csv,noheader)} ${color}Pwr:${color green}${execpi .001 (nvidia-smi --query-gpu=power.draw --format=csv,noheader)} ${alignr}${color}Freq: ${color green}${execpi .001 (nvidia-smi --query-gpu=clocks.mem --format=csv,noheader)}
${else}
${color2}${voffset 5}Intel® Skylake GT2 HD 530 iGPU @  ${color green}${execpi .001 (cat /sys/class/drm/card0/gt_cur_freq_mhz)} MHz
${color}${goto 13}Min. Freq:${goto 120}${color green}${execpi .001 (cat /sys/class/drm/card0/gt_min_freq_mhz)} MHz${color}${goto 210}Max. Freq:${goto 320}${color green}${execpi .001 (cat /sys/class/drm/card0/gt_max_freq_mhz)} MHz
${color orange}${hr 1}
```